# TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'getProperty'

Tags: javascript, php, breeze

I'm kind of new to this whole posting a question thing, so please be gentle!

I am using Breeze as part of the "Hot Towel" SPA stack and retrieving data from a custom WebApi endpoint written in PHP. It's not a full implementation, I've just written enough to give me what I need.

The metadata my endpoint is generating is as follows:

```
 {
        "shortName": "Project",
        "namespace": "WebApi.ORM.Cartesius",
        "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity",
        "defaultResourceName": "Project",
        "dataProperties": [
            {
                "name": "id",
                "isPartOfKey": true,
                "isNullable": false,
                "dataType": "Int32"
            },
            {
                "name": "title",
                "isNullable": false,
                "maxLength": 256,
                "dataType": "String"
            },
            {
                "name": "date",
                "isNullable": false,
                "dataType": "DateTime"
            },
            {
                "name": "review_date",
                "isNullable": true,
                "dataType": "DateTime"
            },
            {
                "name": "summary",
                "isNullable": true,
                "dataType": "String"
            }
        ],
        "navigationProperties": [
            {
                "name": "Team",
                "entityTypeName": "Team:#WebApi.ORM.Cartesius",
                "isScalar": true,
                "associationName": "team_project_id_fkey",
                "invForeignKeyNames": [
                    "project_id"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "ProjectAuthor",
                "entityTypeName": "ProjectAuthor:#WebApi.ORM.Cartesius",
                "isScalar": true,
                "associationName": "project_author_project_id_fkey",
                "invForeignKeyNames": [
                    "project_id"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Itinerary",
                "entityTypeName": "Itinerary:#WebApi.ORM.Cartesius",
                "isScalar": true,
                "associationName": "itinerary_project_id_fkey",
                "invForeignKeyNames": [
                    "project_id"
                ]
            },
```

Everything is working fine until I try and do an expand on my query:

```
var query = new breeze.EntityQuery()
        .from("Project")
        .where("id","eq",project.id)
        .expand("ProjectAuthor");
```

This query returns the following from my endpoint:

```
[
{
    "$id": 1,
    "$type": "WebApi.ORM.Cartesius.Project",
    "id": 2,
    "title": "teat",
    "date": "2013-11-04 14:00:00+07",
    "review_date": null,
    "summary": null,
    "ProjectAuthor": [
        {
            "$id": 2,
            "$type": "WebApi.ORM.Cartesius.ProjectAuthor",
            "id": 1,
            "account_id": 1,
            "project_id": 2,
            "Project": [
                {
                    "$ref": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "$id": 3,
            "$type": "WebApi.ORM.Cartesius.ProjectAuthor",
            "id": 3,
            "account_id": 2,
            "project_id": 2,
            "Project": [
                {
                    "$ref": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Then Breeze chokes on it throwing:

```
TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'getProperty'
```

Debugging points to line 5059 in Breeze where it tries to getProperty on an array of entities rather than a single entity I assumed this had something to do with whether the navigation property was set to scalar or not but switching them around made no difference.

I'm sure I'm doing something massively wrong, but I can't figure out what it is and I've kind of hit a brick wall. I've read the docs from top to bottom and am implementing this as best as I can understand but it's possible I'm a little confused.

Thanks in advance for any help and apologies if I have not made myself clear or provided enough info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is in the metadata

```
     "name": "ProjectAuthor",
            "entityTypeName": "ProjectAuthor:#WebApi.ORM.Cartesius",
            "isScalar": true,
            "associationName": "project_author_project_id_fkey",
            "invForeignKeyNames": [
                "project_id"
            ]
        },
```

On that nav property Project->ProjectAuthor your telling it that its a scalar but its not in the data set.. 
    "ProjectAuthor": [
        {
            ..........

I've had this problem aswell .. 99% time its a metadata problem, if not there then start cutting metadata apart until you isolate the error .. though I'm sure thats the problem.. you need a hasMany there and an isScalar on the inverse navigation